# Preventing a specific CSS file from getting loaded in Yii

Tags: php, css, yii

I am coding in Yii.

I have registered the main.css file in my main.php layout file like so :

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($this->assetsBase.'/css/main.css');
```

Now this script is being registered in all the pages. However, say I don't want that script to be registered on a specific page.

I know that using :

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->reset();
```

would remove all the CSS files, however I want only few CSS files to be unregistered.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`scriptMap` property of `CClientScript`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#scriptMap-detail) in your specific view, passing `false` for the particular script/css file's key that you don't want to be rendered. From the doc:

> The array keys are script file names (without directory part) and the array values are the corresponding URLs. If an array value is false, the corresponding script file will not be rendered.

For example, in say *views/site/pages/about.php*:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap = array(
    'main.css' => false
);
```

to disable the inclusion of *main.css* registered with `registerCssFile`.

The `scriptMap` can also be used for controlling the rendering of js script files.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either:

Using a separate layout for that page like `main_no-css.php` 
or
Adding a condition before registering the script (like if controller != xxx and action != yyy), but this would cause the condition to be checked on every other page.

I would definitely go for a separate layout.